# eclipse plugin for jason (Agentspeak) could not open the editor

Tags: eclipse, agent, multi-agent

I've followed Jason Eclipse Plugin mini-tutorial (http://jason.sourceforge.net/mini-tutorial/eclipse-plugin/) but after the installation the editor is not highlighting and showing asl and mas2j code properly.

For asl and mas2j files eclipse is showing the error message: Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

I can ask to eclipse to open as normal text, everythingelse works well. Does anyone knows how to fix this editor error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given by Maicon Rafael Zatelli:

This error is usually due to not compatible version of Eclipse. The
Jason Eclipse plugin is only compatible with JEE and Committers
versions of Eclipse. So, please, check your Eclipse version or
download one of the following versions below and reinstall the plugin:

Here you can get the supported versions of Neon:
Committers: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers/neon3
JEE: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/neon3

Here you can get the supported versions of Luna:
JEE: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr2
Committers: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers-442/lunasr2

Here you can get the supported versions of Mars:
Committers: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers-450/marsr
JEE: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/marsr

When you install the plugin, please make sure if you are opening the
Eclipse with a clean (new) workspace.

*I've installed Eclipse Oxygen for JEE which also is working fine.